# Change PySerial or other module

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I would like to know if exist any other module to communicate via serial in python, instead of PySerial.

I want to know this because, PySerial only communicate with "string", and i have a microcontroller that will receive data from a BeagleBone Black, and i shouldnt do an algoritm on this microcontroller to change strings to int or bytes, because will spend a lot of processing, and every character on a string uses one byte, and that will occupate a lot on this micro.

Saying this, i want to send data in int/hex or binary format instead of string from the BeagleBone side, other solution can be change the PySerial module to do this.

Any help will be aprecciated.

Best Regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct Lib worked to solve my problem.

Example (send a decimal 170 only in one byte):

**Decimal:** ser.write(170) don't work

**Hexadecimal:** ser.write(AA) or ser.write(0xAA) don't work

**String:** ser.write("170") have 3 bytes

**String:** ser.write('AA') have 2 bytes, ser.write('0xAA') have 4 bytes

> struct.pack('B',170) => '\xAA'  (See struct lib documentation)

**Hexadecimal String**    ser.write('\xAA') have only 1 byte

In the receiver side use:

```
data_output = ser.read(1)
struct.unpack('B', data_output)
```

Output:
170

Answer (score -1):

What version of PySerial and Python are you using? You probably just need to upgrade.

According to [PySerial documentation](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write), current version writes bytes natively:

> **write(data)**
>
> Write the bytes data to the port. This should be of type bytes (or compatible such as bytearray or memoryview). Unicode strings must be encoded (e.g. 'hello'.encode('utf-8').

I checked this for PySerial 3.2.1 with Python 3.4.2 and I can confirm it properly writes bytes as requested.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)